# Are transition maps diffeomorphisms?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

For two charts $(U, \phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ on a topological manifold that are $C^\infty$-compatible, the transition maps

$$\phi \circ \psi^{-1}:\psi(U \cap V)\rightarrow \phi(U \cap V)$$
$$\psi\circ\phi^{-1}: \phi(U \cap V) \rightarrow \psi (U \cap V)$$

are $C^\infty$. Are they diffeomorphisms? Intuitively I think that they will be bijective and hence diffeomorphisms but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: A $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphism (between open sets in Euclidean spaces) is by definition a $C^{\infty}$ bijective map with $C^{\infty}$ inverse. The map $\phi \circ \psi^{-1} : \psi(U \cap V) \to \phi(U \cap V)$ seems to satisfy this definition.

Comment: @Mason How can I know that the map is bijective?

Comment: Charts are by definition homeomorphisms onto their images. In particular, they are bijections. The restrictions of the domain and codomain you wrote ensure the map $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is bijective. Even without knowing the charts were $C^{\infty}$ compatible, $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is always a homeomorphism (with the domain and codomain you wrote).

Answer (score 1):

$\phi  : U \to U'$ and $\psi : V \to V'$ are homeomorphisms onto open $U', V' \subset \mathbb R^n$. They restrict to homeomorphisms $\bar \phi  : U \cap V \to \phi(U \cap V) \subset U'$ and  $\bar \psi  : U \cap V \to \psi(U \cap V) \subset V'$. The set $U \cap V$ is open in $M$, the sets $\phi(U \cap V)$ and $\psi(U \cap V)$ are open in $U'$ and $V'$, respectively, and therefore open in $\mathbb  R^n$.

This allows us to define
$$\phi \circ \psi^{-1}:\psi(U \cap V)\stackrel{\bar \psi^{-1}}{\to} U \cap V \stackrel{\bar \phi}{\to}\phi(U \cap V)$$
$$\psi \circ \phi^{-1}:\phi(U \cap V)\stackrel{\bar \phi^{-1}}{\to} U \cap V \stackrel{\bar \psi}{\to}\psi(U \cap V)$$
These maps are homeomorphisms between open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. By assumption they are smooth. Since they are inverse to each other, they are diffeomorphisms.